# How to pick a random item from a listbox in visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, random, listbox, listboxitem

How can i pick a random item from a listBox.This is what i have tried.

```
Public currentTrack As Integer
Public temp As Integer
Public generic As Random = New Random()
temp = gen.Next(0, listTracks.Items.Count + 1)
        currentTrack = temp
        MessageBox.Show(listTracks.Items(currentTrack))
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listTracks.Items(currentTrack)
```

When i display the picked item at a messagebox it pops up 2 message Boxes.Each message box displays a different item.
example: the first messagebox shows C:\test\blab.mp3
and the second shows C:\test\bleasds.mp3

Comment: Something doesn't make sense: `currentTrack = temp`? You haven't put any value in either. Is `tempInt` supposed to be `temp`?

Comment: yea tempInt is temp.I made a mistake

Comment: Firstly, get rid of the `+ 1`.  That's wrong.  As for the issue, the code you have shown us only displays a single message box so, if you're seeing two, that obviously means that you're executing the code twice. Also, don't create a new `Random` instance each time.  Create one and use it repeatedly.

Comment: i should type-1 instead?

Comment: also the variabe random is created when the program loads.It is not created every time

Comment: *"i should type-1 instead?"* I probably would have said that if that was the case. Just think about it logically. The max limit when you call `Next` needs to be 1 greater than the actual max value you want to generate and the `Count` property is 1 greater than the index of the last item. Seems like a match made in heaven.

Comment: when i show the value of currenttrack to a message box it still pops up 2 message boxes

Comment: @ΣτελιοςΛιακοπουλος If it pops up 2 message boxes then the code in the question must be getting called twice. What event happens to run that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim currentTrack As Integer, temp As Integer, gen As Random = New Random()
    Do
        temp = gen.Next(0, listTracks.Items.Count)
        currentTrack = temp
        Dim result1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(listTracks.Items(currentTrack).ToString + vbNewLine + "Play ?",
                                                  "Play", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result1 = DialogResult.Yes Then
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer2.URL = listTracks.Items(currentTrack).ToString
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @ΣτελιοςΛιακοπουλος : Begging for upvotes is not how we do things here. Stack Overflow is very quality-oriented. People will upvote if they find your question interesting, useful, well-asked, helpful to others or of certain future value. They will downvote if it is unclear, badly formatted, is missing information or shows no signs of effort. Right now yours is +/-0, which means it is somewhere in-between.

Comment: @ΣτελιοςΛιακοπουλος : If you want to get more upvotes the best is to figure out what is missing and improve your asking skills. A good way to do that is to read through various entries in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) under the "Asking" section, browse through the [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and reading Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: i just want to complete a challenge